# Is string to dict conversion possible in python?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

We can convert a dict into string but can we convert string back to dict ??

**code**

```
c={'a':3,'b':445}
d=str(c)
```

here can i replace d to type dict.

I want to take dict in form of string and encrypt all numeric digits at once using a key and retain back the dictionary with encrypted numbers.

Comment: You really don't need to convert the `dict` to a string to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I get your question right, you can achieve it this way:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(d)
{'a': 3, 'b': 445}
```

Comment: This works fine but it does automatic round up   in case of float elements which is creating difficulty now

Comment: @ceasif I don't see any roundup:  http://ideone.com/GAI2bJ

Comment: `mapping = df.to_dict()
d=str(mapping)
e= ast.literal_eval(d)
print d
print e
`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) tool.

Usage of it is easy.

```
import json
test = {"a": 1}

# Change dict to string
json_str = json.dumps(test)
print "json_str:= ", json_str

# Change string to dict
json_obj = json.loads(json_str)
print "json_obj:= ", json_obj
```

Comment: this doesnot work when the values associated to keys are tuple :(

Comment: @ceasif you are right. It cast tuple object to list. ast.literal_eval is right way for string to dict. Thanks for the warning :).